# How to remove default transitions in Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the following sippet of code to navigate from a composable to another one, but it has a default fade animation. How can I remove it? I tried using an empty `anim` resource but it doesn't work.

```
navHostController.navigate(
    "destination_route",
    navOptions {
        popUpTo("this_route") {
            inclusive = true
        }
        anim {
            enter = R.anim.empty_animation
            exit = R.anim.empty_animation
            popEnter = R.anim.empty_animation
            popExit = R.anim.empty_animation
        }
    }
)
```

R.anim.empty_animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Empty to disable animation-->
</set>
```

Answer (score 13):

if you use version `navigation-compose:2.7.5` or above, you need to add `enterTransition` and `exitTransition` in `NavHost`.

```
NavHost(navController = rememberNavigationBarController,
        startDestination = "home",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(it),
        enterTransition = {
            // you can change whatever you want transition
            EnterTransition.None 
        },
        exitTransition = {
            // you can change whatever you want transition
            ExitTransition.None
        }) {
        composable("home") {}
        composable("cinema") {}
        composable("ticket") { }
    }
```

Comment: If it is a version before 2.7.0, it is valid, but in later versions, a zoom animation will appear. There seems to be no solution. At the same time, I also saw that some people also have this problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297258205#comment1

Answer (score 6):

**Update Navigation 2.7+**

As mentioned by others, the navigation library now offers us the ability to disable the default fade transitions via `EnterTransition.None` and `ExitTransition.None`.
This is a cleaner approach and should be preferred over the option I presented.

With that being said, there are some use cases that can only be handled by the solution from the original answer. The `None` transitions make it so the screen in question appears/disappears right away. Unfortunately, they offer no synchronisation with other transitions that may be in progress.
Take this scenario as an example, we have a screen `B` that we want to slide up over another screen `A`. If we were to use `ExitTransition.None` on screen `A`, the content of screen `A` will disappear as soon as the `slide-up` animation starts (even though screen `B` hasn't expanded to the full screen yet), thus diminishing the desired effect. In such situations there is no other way than to use the solution from the oringal answer: using a "fake" transition that has the same duration as the `slide-up` transition to ensure that the screen stays visible for as long as we need it.

**Original** **Answer**

As of, 2023, there still seems to be no way to remove the default `crossfade` animation.
However, you could get very close by using something like this:

```kotlin
val noEnterTransition : AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition = {
    fadeIn(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300),
        initialAlpha = 0.99f
    )
}

val noExitTransition : AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition = {
    fadeOut(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300),
        targetAlpha = 0.99f
    )
}
```

This *custom transition* fades out from `100%` opacity to `99%` over the course of the animation duration (which will be imperceptible to the naked eye).

The only thing to **watch out for** is that after the `durationMillis` of the animation passes, the *screen* will disappear altogether.
So if you need it to stay visible for longer (if you have a long enter animation that replaces the current `composable`), you will need to increase the `duration` of the *animation*.
So choose the minimum `duration` that covers your needs (since we want to avoid unnecessary interpolation of the `opacity`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you use this? What is `NavAnimationScope`?

Comment: @lenooh Apologies, `NavAnimationScope` is a type alias I made for the rather long `AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>`.
Thanks for pointing out my oversight, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, I think since navigation 2.7 you can use for example `enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None }` and `exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }` to disable the default fade animation.

Comment: @lenooh Sorry for the late reply, but I now got around to checking this again. Please check my updated answer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to configure the animations in the NavHost offered by Navigation-Compose's current version (2.4.0-beta02).

> ```
> @Composable
> public fun NavHost(
>     navController: NavHostController,
>     graph: NavGraph,
>     modifier: Modifier = Modifier
> ) {
>     val backStackEntry = visibleTransitionsInProgress.lastOrNull() ?: visibleBackStack.lastOrNull()
>
>     var initialCrossfade by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
>     if (backStackEntry != null) {
>         // while in the scope of the composable, we provide the navBackStackEntry as the
>         // ViewModelStoreOwner and LifecycleOwner
>         Crossfade(backStackEntry.id, modifier) { //// <<----- this
> ```

As `Crossfade` is not configurable, the transition cannot be changed.

To change the animation, you have to abandon using the `NavHost` provided by Navigation-Compose.